# Is there a way to catch container-generated STDOUT within embedded Jetty Logback?

Tags: jetty, stdout, logback, rollingfileappender

Situation is:

-> a homemade container app, using logback, configured with ConsoleAppender. Different loggers to specify log levels depending on package:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.package1">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.mycompany.package2">
    <level value="INFO"/>
</logger>
```

-> an embedded Jetty app, using logback, configured with RollingFileAppender.

I need both log outputs to be sent to the same rolling file, so I'm trying to catch the container STDOUT within the embedded Jetty app. Is there a way to do that? is it the wrong way to go about it?

NOTE: I have access to both logback.xml for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logback configuration going to `ConsoleAppender` then don't attempt to catch output and log it again (you just created a loop).

Instead, just configure Jetty to use slf4j for its own events and NOT use the `RolloverFileOutputStream` or the [`console-capture` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-util/src/main/config/modules/console-capture.mod) (from jetty-home).

The easiest way is to not do anything, the mere existence of `slf4j-api-<ver>.jar` in the server classpath is sufficient to make Jetty use slf4j to log its own events on.

In short, your server classpath needs:

- `slf4j-api-<ver>.jar`
- Your logback jars (probably `logback-classic-<ver>.jar` and `logback-core-<ver>.jar`)
- A `${jetty.base}/resources/` directory on your classpath with 2 files:

  - a `jetty-logging.properties` with a single line `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog`
  - your logback configuration files. (eg: `logback.xml`)

Make sure you are **not** using [Jetty's `RollingFileOutputStream` to capture `System.out` and/or `System.err` to a file](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-util/src/main/config/etc/console-capture.xml).